# Argument is of length zero in if statement using R

Tags: r

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

```
for (x in 1:nrow(homer1)-1) {if ((homer1$Start [x+1] +1) == homer1$End [x]) {homer1$annnot_prom <- paste(homer1$Detailed.Annotation, homer1$Nearest.PromoterID, sep="_") } else {homer1$annnot_prom <- homer1$Detailed.Annotation} }

Error in if ((homer1$Start[x + 1] + 1) == homer1$End[x]) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Comment: One or both of the values being compared is probably `NA` . Almost certainly due to operator precedence rules.  Try  `for(x in 1:(nrow(homer1)-1)`

Comment: Study `help("Syntax")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some brackets to your `for` loop:

`for (x in 1:(nrow(homer1)-1))`